# Extract a typedef/using definition from a template class

Tags: c++, templates, types, casting

Is there a way to extract a typedef from a template class? For example, this is what I would like to do:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
class Foo{
public:
   typedef T(*Functor)(Args...);
   Foo() = default;
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
Foo<T, Args...> make_foo(T(*f)(Args...)){
    return Foo<T, Args...>;
}

int bar(int i){
    return i * 2;
}

using type = make_foo(bar)::Functor;
```

I cannot do this. However, I can do this:

```
using type = Foo<int, int>::Functor;
```

This sort of defeats the purpose for me. Is there any way to wrap a function such that I can extract it in type form?

Answer (score 5):

Would [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) be good enough?

```
using type = decltype(make_foo(bar))::Functor;
```

Comment: Wow, so obvious... Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use `decltype`:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
class Foo{
public:
   typedef T(*Functor)(Args...);
   Foo() = default;
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
Foo<T, Args...> make_foo(T(*f)(Args...)){
    return Foo<T, Args...>{}; // Small compilation error fixed here.
}

int bar(int i){
    return i * 2;
}

using type = decltype(make_foo(bar))::Functor;
```

This operator returns the type of the expression it is fed with.